# Invalid operator found in javascript (switch) how can i solve this code

Tags: javascript, html, switch-statement

```html
    <form action="">
        <h2>Inter A Numbers</h2>
        <label for="">Number One</label>
        <input type="text" id="num1">
        <br>
        <br>
        <label for="">Number Tow</label>
        <input type="text" id="num2">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="button" onclick="operator()" value="Multiply">
        <input type="button" onclick="operator()" value="Divide">
        <input type="button" onclick="operator()" value="Addition">
        <input type="button" onclick="operator()" value="Subtraction">
        <input type="button" onclick="operator()" value="Clear">
    </form>
    <p>The Result Is: <br>
        <span id="result"> </span>
    </p>
```

```js
<script>

    let result;
    const number1 = document.getElementById("num1");
    const number2 = document.getElementById("num2");
    switch(number1,number2) {
    case '+':
        result = number1 + number2;
        document.write(`${number1} + ${number2} = ${result}`);
        break;
    
    case '-':
         result = number1 - number2;
         document.write(`${number1} - ${number2} = ${result}`);
        break;
    
    case '*':
         result = number1 * number2;
         document.write(`${number1} * ${number2} = ${result}`);
        break;
    
    case '/':
         result = number1 / number2;
         document.write(`${number1} / ${number2} = ${result}`);
        break;
    
    default:
        document.write('Invalid operator found');
        break;

}
<script/>
```

Comment: How will either "number1" or "number2" ever be one of those operator strings? Also that `switch()` expression is exactly the same as `switch (number2)`; I'm not sure what you intended that to do, but that's not how `switch` works.

Comment: I want to make a code for the arithmetic operations ( + - * / ) using html
And that the user enters two numbers and presses one of the buttons to show the result
using (switch)

Comment: Also that script is executed running when the page is loaded, not when one of those buttons are clicked. They attempt to call an `operator()` function which is not defined anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** You should pass an operator in `opeartor` function throgh JS as:

```
<input type="button" onclick="operator('*')" value="Multiply">
```

**2)** Your script will run once, so better to create a function and call it on button click.

**3)** You need to have `value` for `mathematical opeartion`

```
const number1 = +document.getElementById( "num1" ).value;
const number2 = +document.getElementById( "num2" ).value;
```

```js
const display = document.getElementById("result");

function operator(op) {
  let result;
  const number1 = +document.getElementById("num1").value;
  const number2 = +document.getElementById("num2").value;
  switch (op) {
    case '+':
      result = number1 + number2;
      display.textContent = `${number1} + ${number2} = ${result}`;
      break;

    case '-':
      result = number1 - number2;
      display.textContent = `${number1} - ${number2} = ${result}`;
      break;

    case '*':
      result = number1 * number2;
      display.textContent = `${number1} * ${number2} = ${result}`;
      break;

    case '/':
      result = number1 / number2;
      display.textContent = `${number1} / ${number2} = ${result}`;
      break;

    case 'clear':
      display.textContent = "";
      break;

    default:
      display.textContent = 'Invalid operator found';
      break;

  }
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <h2>Inter A Numbers</h2>
  <label for="">Number One</label>
  <input type="text" id="num1">
  <br>
  <br>
  <label for="">Number Tow</label>
  <input type="text" id="num2">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="button" onclick="operator('*')" value="Multiply">
  <input type="button" onclick="operator('/')" value="Divide">
  <input type="button" onclick="operator('+')" value="Addition">
  <input type="button" onclick="operator('-')" value="Subtraction">
  <input type="button" onclick="operator('clear')" value="Clear">
</form>
<p>The Result Is: <br>
  <span id="result"> </span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your expression inside Switch is wrong

```
switch(number1,number2)
```

As per [W3 schools docs](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp)

This is how your switch statements should look like

```
switch(expression) {
  case x:
    // code block
    break;
  case y:
    // code block
    break;
  default:
    // code block
}
```

And this is how it works:

1. The switch expression is evaluated once.
2. The value of the expression is compared with the values of each case.
3. If there is a match, the associated block of code is executed.
4. If there is no match, the default code block is executed.

I guess you want to get the value of the operator,

instead of using

```
switch(number1,number2)
```

you should get a reference for your operator

e.g.

```
    const operator= document.getElementById("operator");
```

and then make your switch over your operator

```
switch(operator)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an expression in [Switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch). An expression is what is matched against each case clause. In your case, the expression is a character determining the operator ('+', '-', '/', '*'). Also, there is no function called `operator` in your script. I think this is how it should work:

```js
function operator(operation) {
  let result;
  const number1 = Number(document.getElementById("num1").value);
  const number2 = Number(document.getElementById("num2").value);

  if (!operation) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("num1").value = "";
    document.getElementById("num2").value = "";
  } else if (isNaN(number1) || isNaN(number2))
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Invalid operation found";
  else {
    switch (operation) {
      case '+':
        result = number1 + number2;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = (`${number1} + ${number2} = ${result}`);
        break;

      case '-':
        result = number1 - number2;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = (`${number1} - ${number2} = ${result}`);
        break;

      case '*':
        result = number1 * number2;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = (`${number1} * ${number2} = ${result}`);
        break;

      case '/':
        result = number1 / number2;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = (`${number1} / ${number2} = ${result}`);
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <h2>Inter A Numbers</h2>
  <label for="">Number One</label>
  <input type="text" id="num1">
  <br>
  <br>
  <label for="">Number Tow</label>
  <input type="text" id="num2">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="button" onclick="operator('*')" value="Multiply">
  <input type="button" onclick="operator('/')" value="Divide">
  <input type="button" onclick="operator('+')" value="Addition">
  <input type="button" onclick="operator('-')" value="Subtraction">
  <input type="button" onclick="operator()" value="Clear">
</form>
<p>The Result Is: <br>
  <span id="result"> </span>
</p>
```

Comment: "*You need to pass an expression in Switch*" - OP *did* put an expression in the `switch` statement

Comment: I meant expression in terms of this particular use case, which is the operator symbol. I added the same now. Thanks for pointing out.